# Exception in executing publishing : Method not found ProjectUsesAzureAD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

In VS 2015 Community, while publishing MVC project I get the error:

Exception in executing publishing : Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureAD.Contracts.IVsAzureADService.ProjectUsesAzureAD(System.String, System.String ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef, )'.

[image]

I reinstalled 2 times Visual Studio, but not solved yet.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was something linked to Windows 10 updates problem also. Since I did not find any solution anywhere for above error, I decided to reset OS Windows 10 Pro. Then I installed VS 2015 update 3. And it simply works now.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset OS Windows 10 Pro"? Did you do a full reinstall of Windows?

Comment: @DReimer , yes I reinstall. But I am not saying that it is the only solution. I am sure that solution might be something else, but unfortunately I could not find anywhere. Approx one month later, I had to reinstall Windows.